# Connect to a multiple db(n db) java spring hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I want to make a new MS in spring boot, 
my app need to connect to multiple db (for now its 40 different servers but lets say N ).
i have an api that gives me the user name and password of the db i want.
i want to have a map of DB.
i see only configurations on

```
#application.properties

dbc.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb
jdbc.username = root
jdbc.password = password
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql = false
hibernate.format_sql = false
```

---

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({ "com.springhibernate.example.configuration" })
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
public class HibernateConfiguration {


@Autowired
private Environment environment;

@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.springhibernate.example.model" });
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    return sessionFactory;
 }

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
    dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
    return dataSource;
}

private Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
    properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
    return properties;        
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
   HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
   txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
   return txManager;
}
```

I want to make an api call to get the cardential and then to init db, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use spring transaction manager and configure as many as you want  for each db and define separate data sources then would he able to configure multiple databases using spring and hibernate.[enter link description here](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/19676-spring-hibernate-allow-two-database-connection-in-one-project)

[click here to see more](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/19676-spring-hibernate-allow-two-database-connection-in-one-project)

Comment: and if i want it to be dynamically?

Comment: Could you please describe your exact usecase.

Comment: I want to make like a map that i can use for each db, lets say the map is: {db1 : 127.0.0.1, db2 : 172.16.20.177, .... dbn : 172.16.20.188} and i want to call each db by the value

Comment: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/80649-dynamic-database-switching

Comment: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/80649-dynamic-database-switching

Answer (score 0):

See this also ..  http://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/

Thus could be helpful as well Also here

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/80649-dynamic-database-switching